# Installing Google Maps SDK Without Cocapods

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

Any simple way to download the iOS SDK like before? Previously I could just go online and download it from Google and simply add it into my xCode project now it seems all complicated with the Cocoapod install stuff..

Is there any simple way around this just to simply download the SDK from Google like I used to be able to do before??

Thanks,

Curtis

Comment: That won't work Maulik I have tried already but they seem to have deleted the SDK from Github to encourage people to use the Cocoapods.

Comment: you must use cocapods without cocopods you can't get google sdk...